# Removing Mysterious Double Tabs in Python's csv.reader

Tags: python, excel, string, csv, file

I'm taking a lesson on the CSV module.

Pesky `'\t\t'`'s are appearing on the last value of each line, which is an email value.

```
> ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email'] ['John', 'Doe',
> 'john-doe@bogusemail.com\t\t'] ['Mary', 'Smith-Robinson',
> 'maryjacobs@bogusemail.com\t\t'] ['Dave', 'Smith',
> 'davesmith@bogusemail.com\t\t']
```

I think this is happening because excel adds two tabs after the email, presumably to keep it from being a hyperlink. But this is TMI.

**How can I read this in and strip the `'\t\t'`'s after each email?**

Here's what I have so far:

```
with open('names cs.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for i in reader:
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSV module does not have a way to resolve this. The easiest method would be to clean your data after the import.

Loop through your emails and replace all the '\t' with a blank.

```
emails = ['jeffadfafadsf\t\t','asdfasdfadsfadf\t\t']

for i in emails:
    i = i.replace('\t','')
    print(i) 

#   The same can be accomplished with the following line of code:

emails = [i.replace('\t','') for i in emails]
print(emails)
```

Since your list has more fields, you will need to do something to the effect of this:

```
for i in reader:
    i[2] = i.replace('\t','')
```

If you are curious and want to read any documentation, it can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) and the optional arguments (dialects and formatting parameters) documentation can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params)